# Getting a lot of App Icons makes Out Of Memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I created an app to load all installed applications. It's working fine now.
But with some phones/tablets that have a lot of applications, my app crashes because of Out Of Memory.
Below is the source code to get application info

```
String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
                    String packageName = p.packageName;
                    String appFile = a.sourceDir;
                    long lastUpdated = new File(appFile).lastModified();
                    Drawable icon = a.loadIcon(packageManager);
                    AppSize appSize = calculateSize(p.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
                    App application = new App(appName, packageName, lastUpdated, appSize.getSize(), appSize.getLongSize(), icon, false);
```

Is there any way to optimize above code to avoid out of memory?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Please have look at this link: [Displaying bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Also at this open source library project: [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

when your application needs to display lots of bitmaps, it exceeds allocated memory of application. Also, when they are displayed in grid,list or view pager more memory is consumed while creating each views. hence you need to cache in those images in memory or disc and display them efficiently using the techniques described in those links.

> **Addition**

Take a look at this: 
[Get installed Applications with Name, Package Name, Version and Icon](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon)

Acceptable URI's Examples for [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples):

```
String imageUri = "http://site.com/image.png"; // from Web
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
String imageUri = "content://media/external/audio/albumart/13"; // from content provider
String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)
```

Comment: I tried to use Universal Image Loader. But my application gets icons from device (icons of other applications), so I don't know how to pass the Uri parameter to displayImage() method. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Check updated answer. I used that code snippet and i was able to get application icons loaded into a GridView. But i didn't use UIL.I directly loaded them using setImageDrawable(); as i was able to get icon Drawbles. Since not many apps were installed, i didn't face OOM issue. If you are able to get icon's path(which i don't think is possible) you could use file:/// followed by path and then pass it to imageView.displayImage() method of UIL. if i come up with a working solution using UIL for your problem, i will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! My problem is I don't know how to get the url and pass it to displayImage() method. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, i don't know how to get installed apps icon's path. if you look into the link i have added in the answer, it gives you drawable itself. I think its not possible to get URI path for the apps icon. I am also searching. will let u know if i find anything. Using the drawables is straight forward. you don't need UIL for that. But, since you are facing OOM issue, we need to find some solution for that.

Comment: I'm still looking for the solution. If you found any good solution, please share me here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, take a look at this sample application [http://impressive-artworx.de/2011/list-all-installed-apps-in-style/]. he is using a background thread to load the Bitmap drawable icons. so, i think this approach will solve your OOM issue. Note that, He is not using UIL or BitmapFun example of google android. I tried to come up with a solution using both techniques, but i failed to get it work. I also thought to get icon's path, but couldn't find a way to do that. packageInfo.loadicon is the only way which returns icon drawables.

Comment: @phuc_tran, did you solved this, or why did you mark this as solved?

Comment: Link is broken and I'm facing the same problem now