# OutofMemoryError when creatingBitmp

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-canvas

When Creating bitmap for canvas in `onSizeChanged()` I am getting **`OutOfMemoryError`**

I am creating `Bitmap` like this

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

I am getting `OutOfMemoryError` exception when zooming canvas.

How I can handle this exception?

Comment: Keep a global reference of the bitmap.

Comment: recycle the bitmap after use

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15136744/1289716)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16959054/1567588

Comment: Hi @MAC as per your answer,They have Image path or Image URL.But here I don't have any Image path or URL.I am just creating bitmap as per width and height in onSizeChanged() with Bitmap.Config.RGB_565.So,How I can sample this bitmap.

Comment: But I am getting Exception at the time of creating bitmap @George.So,It's not going to next line.Can you please send me any example.

Comment: there is a no track for out of memory must use it within try catch

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size

Comment: Hey, were you able to fix this issue?